# Функция возвращает указатель на место включения нового элемента

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

Написать функцию, которая производит двоичный поиск места размещения нового элемента в упорядоченном массиве и возвращает указатель на место включения нового элемента. С помощью данной функции реализовать сортировку вставками.
Написала код, но не знаю, как учесть если мой элемент больше последнего элемента из массива или меньше. И вообще не уверена, что код работает правильно, потому что с указателями работаю первый раз. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int search(int* array, int len, int n){
    ////СОРТИРОВКА ВСТАВКАМИ
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        int temp = array[0];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++){
            if (array[i] > array[j]){
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    ////БИНАРНЫЙ ПОИСК
    int *ptr = 0;
    int l = 0, r = len - 1 ;

    while(r>l){
    int mid = (l + r)/2;
        if(n<=array[mid])
            r = mid;
        else
            l = mid +1;
    }if(array[l] == n)
         ptr = &l;
    if(array[l] < n){
        int a = l-1;
        ptr = &a;
    }if(array[l] > n)
        ptr = &l ;  
    return *ptr;
}
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int size,n;
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "Введите цифру: ";
    cin >> n;
    int* mas = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        cin >> mas[i];
    search(mas, size, n);
    int res = search(mas, size, n);
    for(int i = 0;i<size; i++)
        cout<<mas[i]<<" ";
    cout<<"Элемент должен стоять на позиции между "<< res << " и " << res + 1<<" элементом "<< endl;

    delete []mas;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы, видимо, не поняли суть задачи. Вам нужно реализовать [сортировку вставками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), но не в академическом варианте, как у вас под комментарием "////СОРТИРОВКА ВСТАВКАМИ". А так, чтобы для поиска места вставки использовался бы бинарный поиск. Вот смотрите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В черных рамках изображены элементы отсортированной части массива. Как видите, отсортированная часть всегда находится в начале, при этом известно где она заканчивается. Мы последовательно сравниваем соседние элементы, если следующий элемент оказывается меньше предыдущего, то он перемещается в правильное место отсортированной части. Вот для поиска этого правильного места от вас и требуется применить бинарный поиск.

К стати, стоит заметить, что в реализации с бинарным поиском, сортировка вставками имеет худшую производительность чем в академической.

Да, вот еще:

```
int l = 0, r = len - 1 ;

while(r>l)
{
    int mid = (r - l)/2; // а не (l + r)/2;
    if(n <= array[mid])
        r = mid;
    else
        l = mid + 1;
}
//...
if(array[l] < n)
{
    int a = l-1;
    ptr = &a;      // берется указатель на локальную переменную!
}
```

Comment: Ещё стоит сказать, то использование бинпоиска в этом алгоритме абсолютно бессмысленно и только ухудшает производительность.

Comment: можете написать бинарный поиск, а то на Вики только в псевдокоде

Comment: @АсяФилатова А вот это уже не смешно.

Comment: @Cerbo Ладно, ок, не парься сама как нибудь разберусь)

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо

Comment: @АсяФилатова Все еще не смешно.

Comment: @Cerbo: А как вы анимацию делали?

Comment: @VladD Просто гифку взял с википедии, когда картинку вставляешь есть возможность ссылку указать.

Comment: @Cerbo: А, понял :) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, если вам нужен указатель, то и смените возвращаемый тип на указатель: `int*`.

Затем, `l` и `r` — это локальные переменные в функции, они умрут после того, как функция закончится, их память отдадут кому-то другому, и указатель будет указывать на кого бог пошлёт. Это неправильно. Вы должны возвращать указатель на элемент массива, т. к. массив переживёт окончание функции. Например, если вы хотите вернуть указатель на `array[l]`, возвращайте `&array[l]`.

Дерзайте!